# How to change passed parameter in custom event

Tags: jquery

I have a custom event, which rising when new Item created:

Event definition

```
 $.fn.extend({
        OnListItemCreated: function (callback) { $(this).bind('OnListItemCreated', callback);  }
});
```

When item created, call this:

```
dialogListFiled.trigger("OnListItemCreated", newItem);
  .... need to using UPDATED newItem....
```

Event handling:

```
myObject.OnListItemCreated(function (newItem) {
            newItem.CountryId=...
                    ...update some newItem values....
        });
```

How best way to handle newItem and update it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had same problem of yours, i needed to handle new elements creation, i used [Jquery.liveQuery Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery), original live() method cannot monitor creation of elements

Sample: (You can do this simply by adding a class to your elements which you want to monitor)

```
$("[class='mylist']").livequery(function(){ 
    this.CountryId = 1; // handle your element
});
```

Comment: newItem - is not DOM element, it is simple JS object. I don't need monitoring. Only call event and update JS object